# Why isn't there an option to update or delete a Workflow Field Update?

Tags: new

There is no option to Edit or Delete an existing Workflow Field Update. Is there a reason for it? I have System Administrator permissions on the account.

Both the Lightning and the Classic interfaces miss the options.

UPDATE: And of course now I need to update the actual field but can't:
*"Cannot change Record Name type to autonumber; field update exists. (Related field: Name Display Format)"*

NOTE: I am fairly new to the SalesForce interface but otherwise well versed with many CMSs and other web based apps.

[image: List of Workflow Field Updates]

[image: Details of a Workflow Field Update]

Comment: You are not logged in as an administrator. If you were, you'd have the option to edit/delete the field updates.

Comment: I wish it was that simple, but that was the first thing I checked. My account has the System Administrator profile, and the profile has the default permissions AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You are not having System Admin profile or doesn't have `Customize Application` permission enabled at your custom profile.

If you have either of those then Create, Edit and Delete Workflows can be possible.

Refer this screenshot and [User capabilities with 'Customize Application' Profile permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194001&type=1)

[image: field update.]

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but as a System Administrator I do have that permissions. I check in the profile http://snpy.in/gyfvQ9  
PS: Also, I definitely have the option to create Field Updates.